# Xcode12 SwiftUI project create LaunchScreen storyboard

Tags: xcode, swiftui, ios14

Until now I was defining my launch screen background and image in plist.info file, however occasionally image resizes full screen and looks ugly. I therefore would like to use using old storyboard for LaunchScreen.

However when I create new LaunchScreen.storyboard I don't see any content.

How can I go about editing this as launch screen?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a Launch Screen, it should automatically create the view controller for you. Try creating a new file and make sure you are selecting a Launch Screen and not a Storyboard (File -> NEW -> File -> Launch Screen).

Otherwise, I can't see in your photo but on the top right there should be a + icon for the Library. Select that and drag and drop a ViewController onto the scene. You can then edit the ViewController like any other storyboard.

At the end, make sure you go to your Project Navigator -> General -> and update the Launch Screen File to this new file.